# How to design your gems so that they interface nicely with Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

Say I have written a gem which makes lazy calls to the Google Distance API and makes the results available. Something like this:

```
module GoogleDirections
  class Journey
    attr_reader :directions, :origin, :destination

    # Origin and destination can either be string addresses or
    # pairs of lat,long co-ordinates
    def initialize(origin, destination)
      @origin = origin.is_a?(Array) ? origin.join(',') : origin
      @destination = destination.is_a?(Array) ? destination.join(',') : destination
    end

    # calculate the trip distance
    def trip_distance
      @trip_distance ||= directions.inject(0){|sum,leg| sum += leg["distance"]["value"] }
    end

    # This method requests directions from Google when we need to
    def directions
      @directions ||= JSON.parse(# get the directions from )
    end
  end
end
```

So, now I add this gem in my Rails project. Tis rails project has buses with origins and destinations. So what I want to do is to query google for the directions before I save a route to the database.

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_trip_distance

  def set_trip_distance
    self.trip_distance = GoogleDirections::Journey.new(self.origin, self.destination).trip_distance
  end
end
```

but then if I add a trip duration method to my gem, I might end up also setting that on my Bus model. Obviously, if I do that, I should extract the creation of a Journey instance.

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :set_trip_distance, :set_trip_duration

  def journey
    GoogleDirections::Journey.new(self.origin, self.destination)
  end

  def set_trip_distance
    self.trip_distance = journey.trip_distance
  end

  def set_trip_duration
    self.trip_duration = journey.trip_duration
  end
end
```

but the `set_trip_distance` and `set_trip_duration` methods seem to be very similar to each other. I can imagine a case where I might be setting 6 different attributes of the route on the bus. That makes me feel like there must be a better design pattern I can use here.

I guess I could design the Gem in such a way that I can `include` it, but doing that would increase the coupling between the Gem and the column names on my Buses which seems bad?

What is the best option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to give users the opportunity to name their own columns for `Journey` data, that's just what they'll have to do.

But if there's already a journey, why not just make it an association, or wrap it up under some metaprogramming?

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_journey :journey
  # Could define journey origin/dest in terms of Bus fields:
  has_journey :journey, :origin => :starting_loc, :destination => :ending_loc
end
```

That said, depending on what you're actually implementing, it seems more like a bus would have multiple journeys, unless it's a throwaway bus. That would allow some interesting stuff like scheduled journies, journey history, etc.

```
class Bus < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_journeys
end
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. Do you think you might be able to add an outline of the `has_journey` method definition please?